# How to get Yandex Traffic Feed on Android Application

Tags: android, maps, yandex-api

I am very new with Android and i'm trying to get traffic feed from yandex's map service. All i need is getting live feed for Istanbul's general traffic situation as it shown it the map  "İstanbul Trafik Durumu 3. derece 12.27 Yer yer yoğun, akıcı trafik".

I don't need to display map or something else. I read the documentation but didn't found something clear for that. Can you give me some advice on it? Or can you recommend another service to accomplish this task?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like i have to answer my own question :s :D

A friend of mine sent an e-mail to Yandex about this issue and reply was:

(Translated from Turkish to English)

> Hi!
>
> Thank you for your interest Yandex Map Kit APIs haven't brought to
>   Turkey (http://api.yandex.ru/mapkit/)
>
> But you can check our GitHub profile for our softwares which may
>   assist you on iOS and Android development. (
>   https://github.com/yandexmobile/ )